# bezierPathWithArcCenter startAngle is a negative value and what it means?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibezierpath

Currently I am reading a open source code and I noticed he is giving a negative value to startAngle. I just don't know why a negative value, and what it means?

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.width / 2.0, self.bounds.height / 2.0) radius:50 startAngle:-M_PI * 11.0 / 8.0 endAngle:M_PI * 3.0 / 8.0 clockwise:YES]
```

Comment: Why the angle couldn't be negative? You lack of trigonometry notions, it's 2*Pi cyclic.

Comment: @Larme but there already a clockwise option, why assign a negative value.

Comment: The clockwise option doesn't change anything in that case. It just if from the `startAngle` to the endAngle, it's drawing in the clockwise sens, or the other one.

Comment: So, if I assign the start angle a positive value. Will it be the same?

Comment: -M_PI*11/8.0 = -M_PI*11/8.0+2*M_PI, if that really bother you (and you may simplify it), but really, that's nothing. That's just a maths issue.

Comment: I just forgot everything I learned in school. I googled it, and I may have a clue.